# Convert Jquery to Javascript Attempt Failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficulty converting this piece of Jquery code into pure JavaScript.

```
var model = sessionStorage.getItem('themodel');
$('#select0').change(function () {
     var modelValue = $(this).val();
     sessionStorage.setItem('themodel', modelValue );
})
.val(model)
```

Here is my attempt

```
var model = sessionStorage.getItem('themodel');
document.getElementById('select0').options.change(function () {
     var modelValue = this.value;
     sessionStorage.setItem('themodel', modelValue );
})
document.getElementById('select0').options.value = model;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need listen on and set value on `select` instead of `options`

```
var model = sessionStorage.getItem('themodel');
document.getElementById('select0').change(function () {
     var modelValue = this.value;
     sessionStorage.setItem('themodel', modelValue );
})
document.getElementById('select0').value = model;
```

Comment: Just a performance improvement.  Intialise a variable 'var  $select0 = document.getElementById("select0")' and then use it such that $select0.change(callback) and $select0.value = model. It reduces multiple DOM traversal.

Comment: @lucumt now I got this `var select0 = document.getElementById("select0");
select0.addEventListener("change", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
 var make = sessionStorage.getItem('v-make');
 var makeValue = this.value;
 sessionStorage.setItem('v-make', makeValue );
 select0.value = make;
}
`